# How to remove an operational error in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to develop my first website(more specifically, an e-commerce site) with the help of a beginners' tutorial. Adding all the required fields, I tried to save the details for the first product. After this, I received the **operational error** as EXCEPTION TYPE and **no such table: main.auth_user__old** as Exception value. I am providing the exact syntax below:

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method:
POST
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/product/add/
Django Version:
2.1
Exception Type:
OperationalError
Exception Value:
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location:
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 296
Python Executable:
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:
3.8.2
Python Path:
['C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\PycharmProjects\\P1',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\PycharmProjects\\P1\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\PycharmProjects\\P1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\PycharmProjects\\P1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.8.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\RITAJA\\PycharmProjects\\P1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg']
Server time:
Fri, 1 May 2020 16:23:28 +0000
```

**TRACEBACK**:-
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste

```js
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute 
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute 
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
The above exception (no such table: main.auth_user__old) was the direct cause of the following exception: 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner 
            response = get_response(request) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response 
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response 
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in wrapper 
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapped_view 
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py in _wrapped_view_func 
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py in inner 
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in add_view 
        return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapper 
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py in _wrapped_view 
                    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in changeform_view 
            return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in _changeform_view 
                    self.log_addition(request, new_object, change_message) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in log_addition 
        return LogEntry.objects.log_action( 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py in log_action 
        return self.model.objects.create( 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method 
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in create 
        obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save 
        self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in save_base 
            updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _save_table 
            result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in _do_insert 
        return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method 
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _insert 
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in execute_sql 
                cursor.execute(sql, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute 
            return super().execute(sql, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute 
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers 
        return executor(sql, params, many, context) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute 
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py in __exit__ 
                raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute 
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 
...
▶ Local vars 
C:\Users\RITAJA\PycharmProjects\P1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute 
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) 
...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Hi. At first glance It looks like you haven't ran `./manage.py migrate`. But you should show the full traceback in your question and format it correctly. I'd also suggest doing the official tutorial first, rather than one you find on the internet, as it will cover creating and running migrations.

Comment: So Sir, shall I share the entire traceback here?

Comment: Yes, just edit your original post and add it there.

Comment: And, I have run ./manage.py migrate , yet it is showing the same problem

Comment: On the yellow error page, can you please press the button that says something like "switch to copy paste view" and copy/paste from that instead. Also can you use the formatting to format it correctly. Can you also add the full output of `./manage.py migrate -v 3`

Comment: Sorry Sir, I didn't get the formatting point, can you pls elaborate?

Comment: You can find the help page here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - otherwise it's hard to read the output.